# jQuery - index returning 0 or -1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble, with jQuery .index() function.
So what I am trying to do is, when I click on span(.edit) I want to alert the index of an input field (above one). I was testing out some stuff, and index() always returned 0 or -1.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input class="editInput" type="text" />
    <span>Mr. Foo</span>
    <div>
        <span class="edit">Full name</span>
    </div>

    <input class="editInput" type="text" />
    <span>Foo Town</span>
    <div>
        <span class="edit">City</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery statement

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().siblings(".editInput").index());
}
```

I tried a lot of similar things, but none of them worked.

Any idea?

Comment: what is your event that triggers this line?

Comment: Why would you need the index for all potential siblings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).parent().siblings(".editInput")` will select all `.editInput` elements in this case, and calling `.index()` without argument will get the position of the first selected element (the first `.editInput` element) relative to the its siblings, which will be always `0` here.

---

If you want to get the index of the input element relative to the other input element(s), you have to select all of them first:

```
var $inputs = $('#wrapper .editInput');
```

Then you have to find the closest preceding `input` element from the clicked `span`, which you can do with [`.prevAll` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and [`.first` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
var $closest_input = $(this).parent().prevAll('.editInput').first();
```

Then call [`.index` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/index/) on the set of `input` elements, passing the just found `input`:

```
var index = $inputs.index($closest_input);
```

When called this way, `.index` will return the index of the passed element in the set of the selected elements.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("span.edit").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("#wrapper").find(".editInput").each(function(){
        alert($(this).index(":parent .editInput"));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XZEAS/1

Comment: `$(this).parent("#wrapper")` will return an empty set. You probably meant to use `.parents` or `.closest`. *edit:* The OP bound the handler to the `span.edit` elements, not all `span` elements.

Comment: yes I remembered that, but when I tried `.parent`, it worked too. `.closest` would be the best shot I think. I'll modify my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span.edit").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().siblings(".editInput").index());
});
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/uJsg8/

Comment: @FelixKling That's because he edited his post. This is not what the original post said.

Comment: Well, he said *"So what I am trying to do is, when I click on span(.edit) I want to alert the index of an input field (above one). I was testing out some stuff, and index() always returned 0 or -1."*, so you can assume he already bound the event handler. The problem was not binding it, but getting the right index.